# Проблема с кодировкой utf-8 в python скрипте

Tags: python, utf-8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу я на языке python, как мне убрать эти каракули (открывал через encoding utf-8 и в начале скрипта писал `#coding: utf-8`

Comment: Добавь BOM, винда плохо понимает utf8

Comment: А какая вообще цель в открытии этого файла блокнотом?

Comment: получить информацию из файла

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Если этот файл был создан при помощи команды `ipconfig /all > some-file.txt`, то там вообще DOS-кодировка `cp866`:

[image: -]